# Как можно уменьшить/объединить этот код C#(Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public void priceBoost(int numPrice)
    {
        if **(numPrice == 1 && GameManager.banana >= 1000 && GameManager.banana <= 5000)**
        {
            GameManager.price1 += 10;
            GameManager.buy1 += 10;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buy1", GameManager.buy1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("price1", GameManager.price1);
        }

            **if (numPrice == 1 && GameManager.banana >= 10000 && GameManager.banana <= 50000)**
            {
                GameManager.price1 += 100;
                GameManager.buy1 += 100;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buy1", GameManager.buy1);
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("price1", GameManager.price1);
            }

        }
```

Как можно объединить выделенные(находящиеся в **между * звездочками**) строчки кода?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно "упростить" условия и вынести общие части:

```java
public void priceBoost(int numPrice) {
    if (numPrice == 1 && GameManager.banana >= 1000) {
        int boost = 0;
        if (GameManager.banana <= 5000) {
            boost = 10;
        } else if (GameManager.banana >= 10000 && GameManager.banana <= 50000) {
            boost = 100;
        }
        GameManager.price1 += boost;
        GameManager.buy1 += boost;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("buy1", GameManager.buy1);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("price1", GameManager.price1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое, это хоть и маленькая деталь, но все равно код визуально стал меньше)

Comment: @Mizig_ а если больше 50000 бананов, то что?

Comment: @aepot, а если больше 5.000, но меньше 10.000 или меньше 1.000 или вовсе `numPrice` не 1... это код-решето, человек в самом плохом начале пути в котором собирает все анти паттерны программирования, вопрос про детали по значениям не самый важный и смысла не имеет. Впереди бой с последствиями, когда все будет ссыпаться и попыткам исправлений которые лавинообразно приводят к большему ущербу. Это стоит просто пройти, сам когда-то начинал с god классов.

Comment: @aepot, а если больше 5.000, но меньше 10.000 или меньше 1.000 или вовсе `numPrice` не 1... это код-решето, человек в самом плохом начале пути в котором собирает все анти паттерны программирования, вопрос про детали по значениям не самый важный и смысла не имеет. Впереди бой с последствиями, когда все будет ссыпаться и попыткам исправлений которые лавинообразно приводят к большему ущербу, это стоит просто пройти, сам начинал с god классов.

Comment: @Yaroslav, а нужно ли додумывать за автора вопроса лишние проблемы?

Comment: @NowhereMan, если ты программист, то занимаешься формализацией задачи автоматически, не прикладывая особых усилий и потуг. Вопроса "нужно ли" вообще в этом роде деятельности не стоит. То что она поставлена не правильно, не тем языком, не теми словами это нормально. Даже если сам что-то дизайнешь, это так-же придется формализовать.

Comment: Да, я плохой и ленивый программист, который не будет городить кучу кода для решения **чужой тривиальной** задачи.  И 20+ лет назад мне пришлось переписывать с нуля и выбрасывать кучу "гибкого кода", который насочинял очередной двадцатилетний сеньор, так как в те времена его запакованное поделие слишком долго грузилось.

Answer (score 0):

Сокращение и упрощение в программирование как путание теплого с мягким. Их можно не объединять а вовсе выделить в правило, которое само может проверить данные на её соответствие требованиям:

```
_rules = new[]
{
    new Rule(1, 1000, 5000, new Values(10, 10)),
    new Rule(1, 10000, 50000, new Values(100, 100)),
};
```

---

```
foreach (var rule in _rules)
    if (rule.IsConformity(level, value))
    {
        _values = rule.values; // buy1 и price1
        break;
    }
```

После чего добавление новых условий будет занимать всего одну строчку, можно легко написать хоть десятки и никакой вереницы `if else` вообще не будет!

Но для этого нужно учиться декомпозиции задачи на простые элементы и описывать каждый элемент одним классом с одной единственной ответственностью. В результате этого кода якобы больше, но при расширении его по факту меньше и он не посыпится.

Твой пока-что маленький кусочек кода, который намеривается стать пизанской башней одновременно апгрейд, баланс, сохранитель и что только не. `numPrice` это какой-то уровень апгрейда, насколько я понял, и если `price1` и `buy1` жестко зависят от `numPrice` и `banana` то зачем ты сохраняешь первых, а не вторых высчитывая их из первых? Мне кажется что `price1` и `buy1` в принципе существуют в связке и нет смысла их разделять. Стоит написать сущность типа `Upgrade`, которая сама следит за своим состоянием. Правило само по себе сущность, как упомянуть выше. И кто-то кто связывает все во едино.

```
public struct TradePrice
{
    public int buy;
    public int sell;

    public TradePrice (int buy, int sell)
    {
        this.buy = buy;
        this.sell = sell;
    }
}
```

---

```
public struct PriceRequire
{
    public int requireLevel;
    public int minValue;
    public int maxValue;

    public PriceRequire (int requireLevel, int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
        this.requireLevel = requireLevel;
        this.minValue = minValue;
        this.maxValue = maxValue;
    }

    public bool IsConformity (int level, int value)
    {
        return requireLevel == level && value >= minValue && value < maxValue;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Economic
{
    private readonly Dictionary<PriceRequire, TradePrice> _prices; // справочник правил и цен
    private readonly Upgrade _tradeStat; // откуда берем уровень
    private readonly Func<int> _targetValue; // метод возвращающий значение числа (banana)
    private TradePrice _defaultPrice = new TradePrice(1, 1);
    private TradePrice _currentPrice; // buy и price в связке

    public Economic (Func<int> targetValue)
    {
        _targetValue = targetValue;
        _tradeStat = new Upgrade("Trade", 1);
        _prices = new Dictionary<PriceRequire, TradePrice>();
        _prices.Add(new PriceRequire(1, 0, 1000), new TradePrice(1, 1));
        _prices.Add(new PriceRequire(1, 1000, 5000), new TradePrice(10, 10));
        _prices.Add(new PriceRequire(1, 5000, 10000), new TradePrice(50, 50));
        _prices.Add(new PriceRequire(1, 10000, 50000), new TradePrice(100, 100));
        UpdatePrice();
    }

    public TradePrice Price => _currentPrice;

    public void LevelUp ()
    {
        _tradeStat.LevelUp();
        UpdatePrice();
    }

    public void UpdatePrice ()
    {
        foreach (var price in _prices)
            if (price.Key.IsConformity(_tradeStat.Level, _targetValue()))
            {
                _currentPrice = price.Value;
                return; // вместо break завершаем сам метод, а не цикл
            }
        _currentPrice = _defaultPrice; // если в справочнике не оказалось подходящих совпадений
    }
}
```

Остается только написать `Upgrade` который принимает ключ для `PlayerPrefs`, базовый уровень и может сам загружает и сохранять свой уровень. Можно прописывать бесчисленное количество правил, изменять условия с бананов на персики не переписывая фигалион строк кода и в принципе модифицируя конструкцию.

Не думаю что это поможет прямо сейчас, но как ориентир. Думаю что взглянув на пример, удобство дольнейшей работы с таким кодом очевидны даже начинающему. Не бойся писать плохо или даже ужасно, пиши больше что-бы лучше чувствовать в каких местах болит после написанного и появляется желание уметь это лечить.

п.с. `GameManager` это безликая сущность не имеющая смысла, она как мем и не должна существовать. `GameManager.banana`... хм банан... `GameManager` это мартышка или склад?... `GameManager.price` цены! видимо все-таки склад... `GameManager.buy` покупка? походу биржа $#? А у тебя этих полей не связанных между собой там много и не только поля.